# Basis of $P_2$ given a set of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having trouble understanding the answer given. So I solved it down and found the rref of the matrix, but I don't udnerstand why my solution isn't right.
Question: 
Consider a set of polynomials $S = \{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\}$ in $P_2$, where

- $p_1(z) = 1+z-z^2$,

  $p_2(z) = 2-z$,

  $p_3(z) = 5-4z + z^2$,

  $p_4(z) = z^2$.

Show that $S$ is a linearly dependent spanning set for $P_2$, and then find a subset of $S$ which is a basis for $P_2$.

So what I did was found the span of the $p_k$'s and removed one polynomial. However, the one I removed was $p_4$. 
The answer says a basis for $P_2$ would be $\{p_1,p_2,p_4\},\{p_2,p_3,p_4\},\{p_1,p_3,p_4\}$ NOT $\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$.
I don't understand, because when I find the linear combination of $p_1,p_2,p_3$, it is independent and spans $P_2$ as well? Why is my answer not correct?

Thanks!

Comment: How to [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference): to get $P_n$ you type `$P_n$`.  To get $W = \{ (x,y,z) \in \Bbb F \mid x=y^2=2z \}$ you type `$W = \{ (x,y,z) \in \Bbb F \mid x=y^2=2z \}$`.  To get $$A\mathbf x = \mathrm b$$ you type `$$A\mathbf x = \mathrm b$$`.  Now see if you can edit your question to make it more readable.

Comment: Sorry about that! Will use that from now on. Also thank you to Sloan for proposing the edit to me as well

Comment: @ActuarialStudent101: How is proof that $p_1, p_2, p_3$ are linear independent?

Comment: Hmm, I must've made a really stupid mistake.

Would there be an easy way to know which polynomial to remove when doing the 3x4 matrix (in this case)?

Comment: Reduce row with coefficients of polynomial in columns.  Then find a column without a pivot.  That corresponds to a polynomial that can be removed.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily check that:

$ p_1+p_3 = -3z+6 = 3 (p_2) $

So the set $ \{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ is not a basis because it is not linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't that mean the basis should not have either $p_1$ or $p_2$? Since a $p_2$ can be formed by a linear combination of the other polynomials?

Comment: It means that $\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ is not a basis but it could happen that any of those polynomials be in other basis. There could also be a basis including $p_1,p_2$ and another polynyomial linealy independent to those two.If the answer was clear enough you can mark it as accepted!